# Get commands not executing on android 2.3.3 gingerbread

Tags: android, cordova, get

I have a javascript code that submits the data to some other domain server. The data is submitted ok but when iam using the get method to retrieve data from my phonegap app on my device then it wont work. The response from the server should replace my content which is the usual behaviour and it works fine if i execute my get method from my browser window or my android emulator 4.2. But on my phone 2.3.3 gingerbread the post commands execute properly but the server response is not recevied via get.

Thanks,
Any suggestions?

Edit:

As mentioned I am using post and get commands for submitting data to server and retrieving it. I was doing it by using form submission. A new thing now has come up: When I use form submission on mozilla and my android emulator 4.2 it works, but the same code doesn't work on android phone 2.3.6. I now thought of using ajax calls and the code started working on phone but now they don't work on android emulator 4.2 and mozilla. For the same code that works on phone the emulator receives a status of 0. As far as mozilla is concerned cross-domain doesn't work, so i understand what's happening but what about emulator? Why ajax not working on emulator and why form submit works? It looks like emulator and browser are behaving the same way.

again,
any suggestions would really help. I can't test all the time on actual device.